# How to access value attr from click class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.edit', function(){
    var appid = $(this).getAttribute('value');
```

I have an img with the class edit, I was wondering how I can store the value of the "value" attribute?

Comment: what is `click` class. I didn't get you.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you have?

Comment: `click` is an event handler. `edit` is the class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
$(".edit").on('click', function(){
    var appid = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

**references**

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[getattribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Thanks, was close, whats the difference between attr and getattribute ?

Comment: @vinnie667: `.attr()` is a jQuery method, `getAttribute` is a DOM element method. It either has to be `$(this).attr(...)` or `this.getAttribute(...)`.

Comment: @vinnie667: `getAttribute` is a DOM method, available on DOM objects; `attr` is a jQuery method, available on jQuery objects. So your code could be `$(this).attr("value")` or `this.getAttribute("value")`, but not `$(this).getAttribute("value")`. Note that as Amit points out, `value` is not a valid attribute for `img` elements.

Answer (score 4):

There is no valid value attribute on `<img>`. But you can use `data-value`:

```
var appid = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".edit").on('click', function(){
    var appid = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
   var appid = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: *"I have an **img** with the class click"*

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't read close enough. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: maybe it's an input type button with background img... we don't know!

Comment: @Franky You can't assume this, just as you shouldn't assume anything when answering

Comment: @Franky: Or better, ask for clarification.